# C++ SSL Virtualhosting

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, virtualhost

While implementing a C++ Server I came around the problem of having two domains pointing to the same server.
Implementing a standard SSL Server using boost is not really a problem, but I now need to somehow decide which certificate to use when connected.
I know it is possible because it is common practice in Mass Webhosting.

For example a single Apache/nginx is capable of providing two different https websites using two different certificates on the same port (443). I'd like to implement a similar behaviour in C++.

How does apache handle this ?

Is it possible to implement this using boost asio or do I need to use some lower level API (OpenSSL/OS) ?

Comment: can the server recognizes one domain from another based on incoming requests?

Comment: The semantics are quite similar to http.
Once the connection is established I know based on the incoming requests which host it is connected to. But this is too late to decide the certificate. There must be some way without this since it works in Apache to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to tell the server in advance which host is desired is to use Server Name Indication, as described in [RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066). It adds an extension field `server_name` to TLS including a server name list which the server can then use.

This is not a required field, so not all browsers or servers support it. But the support in mainstream products is good at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me quite a bit.
But it seems boost asio does not support it.
Seems I have to use plain OpenSSL.